# Get oldest records from Application Insights REST API using ODATA

Tags: azure, odata, azure-application-insights

We want to get the oldest available events in Application insights, but we always get the last events even if we order by timestamp. It´s only the result that's ordered.

> https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/[id]/events/customEvents?$count=true&$filter=timestamp
>   gt 2000-01-01T00:00:00&$select=timestamp, user/id,
>   customEvent/name&$orderBy=timestamp asc&$top=100

Comment: you just want to get the event data whose date > 2000-01-01T00:00:00?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please use this kind of query, it works at my side:

```
https://api.applicationinsights.io/v1/apps/your_app_id/query?query=customEvents | where timestamp >= datetime('2018-12-11T00:00:00.000')| project timestamp ,name| order by timestamp asc| take 20
```

And the test result with postman:
[image]

Comment: @Lillvik, so can you help mark it as an answer? thanks:)

Comment: Do you know if one ca accomplish it with ODATA instead of query?

Comment: Hi @Lillvik, which tool you used to test this query? I use this online [tool](https://dev.applicationinsights.io/apiexplorer/events?appId=DEMO_APP&apiKey=DEMO_KEY), it works ok and the result is as expected.